# How can I make an auto incrementing number field in a new firestore document?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to make an auto incrementing number field in a new firestore document.
For more details, I am making CRUD example and I want to number the forum's document urls, like forum/1, forum/2, etc. I thought about reading the recent document's id and plus 1, but this would conflict with other users if these requests occur simultaneously. The official document says I should use server timestamp to sort the documents, but I don't want to change the document ID, just want to make a new field which is incrementing.

I considered about firebase cloud functions which are listening to creating documents, but client-side would be nicer. Thank you very much.

Comment: I think I may be a little off in what you are trying to achieve but when making an incremental counter you should use a [transaction operation.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#transaction) You can read more about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write) as well.

Comment: @TroyMyers I think you are right.
I tried to find out about transactions.. it's bit hard.
Anyway, thank you a lot to set the guildline for me!